# Не понятен принцип работы алгоритма

Tags: c

```
for (cz = 0; cz < sizeof(tech) / sizeof(tech[0]); cz++)
{
   if (tech[cz].czasi < 200)
     printf("%s %s %d\n", tech[cz].imja, tech[cz].uczitel, tech[cz].czasi);
}
```

Как я понял, мы сначала получаем переменную (tech) в байтах, далее сравниваем больше либо 200 и далее выводим. Вроде так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sizeof(tech)/sizeof(tech[0])
```

Это такой популярный способ получить размер массива. Поэтому цикл будет выполнятся по всем элементам массива.

Код сделает следующее: для всех элементов массива `tech`, у которых значение поля `czasi` меньше 200, распечатает содержимое полей `imja`, `uczitel` и `czasi`.

Answer (score 1):

Берем каждый элемент массива tech (с индексами от 0 до максимального) и если кол-во часов **меньше** 200, то печатаем на экран поля элемента.